# How to handle change of focus between two specific elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, focus, blur

I have two (or more) HTML elements and I want to execute a callback whenever any of them loses focus except when the focus is moved between them. In other words I want to treat those elements like a single one from the focus point of view and execute a *group-*`onBlur` callback.

Using React I tried to keep track of the the focus of each element on a state, but when moving the focus from element `a` to element `b`, `onBlur` on `a` always happens before `onFocus` on `b`. Also since the state update may be async I'm not sure about the consistency of the state.

Comment: Can you share a code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store refs to each of the inputs that you want to "share" focus and then check if either is focused in your `onBlur` function before taking any actions. Note, however that the focused element is the `body` if you check immediately when the blur happens. To get around this you can wrap your `onBlur` logic in a `setTimeout` call with a delay of `0`ms.

Here's an example:

```js
function MyComponent() {
    const aRef = React.useRef(null);
    const bRef = React.useRef(null);

    function onBlurGroup() {
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            if (document.activeElement === aRef.current || document.activeElement === bRef.current) {
                console.log("a or b is focused");
                return;
            }

            console.log("focus lost from group");
            // do blur handling
        }, 0)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input ref={aRef} name="a" type="text" onBlur={onBlurGroup}/>
            <input ref={bRef} name="b" type="text" onBlur={onBlurGroup}/>
            <input name="other" type="text"/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And a functioning sample (using a class-based component since Stack doesn't support hooks yet):

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.aRef = React.createRef();
        this.bRef = React.createRef();
    }

    onBlurGroup = () => {
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            if (document.activeElement === this.aRef.current || document.activeElement === this.bRef.current) {
                console.log("a or b is focused");
                return;
            }

            console.log("focus lost from group");
            // do stuff
        }, 0)
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input ref={this.aRef} name="a" placeholder="A" type="text" onBlur={this.onBlurGroup}/>
                <input ref={this.bRef} name="b" placeholder="B" type="text" onBlur={this.onBlurGroup}/>
                <input name="other" placeholder="Other" type="text"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent/>, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically you pull it off with a timeout and wait for a few milliseconds before firing text step. Quick and dirty react code.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        blurTimer: null
    }
  this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
  this.handleFocus = this.handleFocus.bind(this);
  }

    clearTimer() {
    if (this.state.blurTimer) {
      window.clearTimeout(this.state.blurTimer);
      this.setState({ blurTimer: null });
    }
  }
  
  processIt() {
    console.log('Process it!!!!');
  }

  handleBlur() {
    this.clearTimer();
    const blurTimer = window.setTimeout(() => this.processIt(), 100);
        this.setState({ blurTimer });
  }

  handleFocus() {
    this.clearTimer();
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>foo</h2>
        <input type="text" onBlur={this.handleBlur} onFocus={this.handleFocus} />
        <input type="text" onBlur={this.handleBlur} onFocus={this.handleFocus} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```